# Proving a particular case of AM-GM graphically

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions

> Sketch a graph of $y = \ln x$ and hence explain why $$\frac{\ln a + 2
>  \ln b}{3} \le \ln\frac{a + 2b}{3}$$

I understand that $\ln $ is a strictly increasing function and $x > y \implies \ln x > \ln y$. With this, it is trivial to show that since

$$\frac{a + b + b}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{a\cdot b \cdot b}$$

then it follows that

$$\ln\frac{a + 2b}{3} \ge \ln\sqrt[3]{ab^2} = \frac{\ln a + 2 \ln b}{3}$$

However, this does not make use of the graph at all. In fact, it is highly likely that this solution is inappropriate: the next part of the question is to derive the AM-GM inequality for this particular case (`Hence derive an ineqauality connecting $ab^2$ and $a + 2b$`).

Comment: But you are using the AM-GM inequality in the proof! I think you are supposed to use the convexity of $\ln$ to prove the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: Yes - I'm checking with the forum to see how to use the graph instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we have $f(x)=\ln(x)$ by differentiating we get $$y''=-\frac{1}{x^2}<0$$ thus we can apply Jensen's inequality
$$\frac{f(a)+f(b)+f(b)}{3}\geq f\left(\frac{a+b+b}{3}\right)$$

Comment: This is good! I'll accept it as soon as I can. (Btw, i think you got the sign in the last statement wrong)

Answer (score 1):

This is related with the convex of the function $\ln x$.